# Merge data frames: Add new levels to factor and match values to newly added factors

Tags: r, merge

I have the following data frames:

```
df1<- data.frame( year= c(rep("2009", 8), rep("2010", 8)), 
                 elev_cat= c(rep("low",4), rep("high",4), rep("low",4), rep("high",4)), 
                 clim_var=c(rep("ppt", 2),rep("tmax", 2), rep("ppt", 2),rep("tmax", 2), rep("ppt", 2),rep("tmax", 2), rep("ppt", 2),rep("tmax", 2)),
                       div_var=c("lep_div", "psit_div", "lep_div", "psit_div", "lep_div", "psit_div","lep_div", "psit_div", "lep_div", "psit_div", "lep_div", "psit_div", "lep_div", "psit_div","lep_div", "psit_div"),
                       div_value=c(5,4,3,2, 5,4,3,2, 8,9,10,11, 8,9,10,11), 
                       clim_value=c(1.5, 1.5, 3.7, 3.7, 3.4, 3.4, 2.5, 2.5,2.1,2.1,3.1,3.1,4,4,5,5 ))


df2<- data.frame(year=c(rep("2009",4), rep("2010", 4)), 
                     elev_cat= rep(c("low", "high"), 4), 
                     clim_var=rep(c("anom1", "anom1", "anom2", "anom2"),2), 
                     clim_value=c(1,2,3.4, 5, 2.17, 3.7, 8.9, 4.5))
```

`df1` contains diversity values `div_value` for various levels of `div_cat` for each `year` and elevation category `elev_cat`. Diversity values remain constant for a given level of `year`, `elev_cat` and `div_cat`. Climate variables are represented by `clim_var`. Corresponding variables for `clim_var` are in `clim_value`.  Annual climate averages remain constant for each `year` and `elevation`.

I want to add `df2` to `df1`. `df2` has additional climate variables for each `year` and `elev_cat`, these values need to be added in such as way that they are repeated for each level of `div_cat` and its corresponding `div_value`.

I have tried:

```
ex<- merge(df1, df2, by=c("year","elev_cat"))
```

however, this adds `df2` information as columns (ie. `clim_var.y` and `clim_var.x`).

The expected result data frame should appear as follows:

```
expected_result<- data.frame( year= c(rep("2009", 16), rep("2010", 16)), 
                          elev_cat= rep(c("low", "low", "high", "high"),8), 
                          clim_var=c(rep("ppt", 4),rep("tmax", 4), rep("anom1", 4),rep("anom2", 4),rep("ppt", 4),rep("tmax", 4), rep("anom1", 4),rep("anom2", 4)), 
                          div_var=rep(c("lep_div", "psit_div", "lep_div", "psit_div"), 8),
                          div_value=c(rep(c(5,4,3,2),4), rep(c(8,9,10,11),4)), 
                          clim_value=c(1.5, 1.5, 3.7,3.7,3.4,3.4,2.5,2.5,1,1,2,2,
                                 3.4, 3.4, 5, 5,2.17,2.17,3.7,3.7, 8.9,8.9,
                                 4.5,4.5,2.1,2.1,3.1,3.1,4,4,5,5))
```

Comment: Each row of `temp` should become 2 rows once added to `df1` because values for `clim_var` and `clim_value` would be repeated for each level of `div_cat` in `df1`.

Comment: Technically, your expected result misses the other half of proper matches. See differences with `merge` and `rbind` approach: https://rextester.com/EVVMV71168.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can `group_split` by 'div_var', loop over the `list` of datasets, bind with 'df2', and then do a group by 'year', 'elev_cat' and `fill` the columns 'div_var', 'div_value' NAs with the previous non-NA value

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_split(div_var) %>%
    map_dfr(~ bind_rows(., df2)  %>% 
    group_by(year, elev_cat) %>% 
    fill(div_var, div_value)) %>%
    ungroup
```